# htmlParse: how to extract elements from HTMLInternalDocument

Tags: java, html, r, parsing

I'm absolutely new to parsing and quite stumbled now. I've downloaded code from webpage with R function `htmlParse` and now want to extract some data from it. It has lots of elements, but i'd like to get data from exact one, starting with `<script type="text/javascript">`. How is it possible to do so and get the needed part of a code in a charachter format so it'll be possible than to extract other small elements from this bulk with, probably, regexp?

Comment: For web scraping, nowadays, you should probably use the `rvest` package - https://github.com/hadley/rvest - and a combination of read_html() and html_nodes(). If it's just extracting some piece of javascript, regex should be fine. For a more detailed answer, you should provide a detailed, practical and reproducible question.

Comment: Oh, sure, thanks! Will try it.